# Is MinGW exactly the same as GCC as far as standards compliance or features?

Tags: gcc, g++, mingw, standards-compliance

As a port, I'd think it'd be hard to keep it completely up to speed with GCC. Is it, or are there any differences with regards to standards compliance or features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a version to version, basis, yes, as far as is possible. In other words 4.4.1 on Windows should be as c++ Standard compliant as 4.4.1 on Linux (for example). But there are, as far as I know, no guarantees of this.

OTOH, will the two implementations work in the same way? Almost certainly not - we've had  a couple of examples of differences posted here recently. But can you use the implementations to port between Windows and Linux - yes, I do this routinely.